# (a^k(p-1)+ b) mod(p) here p is a prime number and a,b,k is an integer greater than 1 and a not divisble by p. Is this value same as (a^b)mod(p)?

Tags: math, primes, modulus, modular-arithmetic

According to Fermat's Little theorem a^(p-1) mod(p) is 1. So a^k(p-1) mod(p)will also be 1 by splitting into k parts and apply modulus independently we get '1'. Am I missing something?

Comment: math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I didn't get any response there

Comment: @Alex you posted your question there **ten minutes ago**. You generally should wait a bit more than **ten minutes** before deciding to cross post to a different site. And in any event this question is clearly off topic here.

Comment: @AakashM okay..but I thought there would be more users here

Comment: That there are more users here doesn't somehow make it OK to ask off topic questions...

Comment: I will agree with alex, any other stack exchange forums are deserted compared to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know,

`((a mod N) * (b mod N)) mod N = (a*b) mod N`

`a^(p-1) mod p = 1`

Thus

`( a^(p-1) * a^(p-1) * a^(p-1) * ... * a^(p-1) ) mod p = ( 1 * 1 * 1 * ... * 1) mod p = 1`

Tada.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.
In general, the equation holds as
a^(k*phi(n)+b) is congruent with a^b modulo n
where phi denotes the Euler-phi function, and a is relative prime to n.